# Split and expand table containing concatenated data in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am using SQL Server 2017:

I have this table:

```
IdProduct  | IdProducers
-----------+------------
A          | 1,2,4
B          | 2,5
```

And I want to get this result:

```
IdProduct  | IdProducer
-----------+-----------
A          | 1
A          | 2
A          | 4
B          | 2
B          | 5
```

What is the optimal solution?

Comment: That question has been asked more than I can count here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can write as below:

```
SELECT IdProduct ,value  
FROM Product  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(IdProducers, ',');
```